# Regex to not match the dashes or a prefix in a string

Tags: regex

I have various strings in the format of `.PREFIX-word1-word2-word3` where PREFIX can be any word and there can be 1 or more words that follow the prefix (in this case word1 word2 word3).

What I'm attempting to do is match on any words that follow the prefix so that in the end I get back just the words (in this case word1 word2 word3). Therefore, I don't want to match on `.PREFIX` or any dashes.

Given that PREFIX can be anything I've been using `(?<=-).*$` which matches `word1-word2-word3`.

What am I missing in order to just match on `word1 word2 word3`?

Comment: So, the PREFIX or individual words might contain a dash?

Comment: `(?<=-)\w+`? See https://regex101.com/r/LG7rKj/1

Comment: Right, so the format is always `.PREFIX-` + `word` + `-` and you can repeat `word` + `-` as many times as you want. However, the last word won't have the dash.

Comment: If dashes are not allowed in words or PREFIX, you could use `[^-]*` instead of `.*`. And remove the `$` at the end.

Comment: Awesome, looks like both Regex are valid ways to get the intended result.

Comment: Ok, I see you have an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude matching the hyphen using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) starting with `[^`

```
(?<=-)[^-]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JZrLQS/1)

If you just want a single word after the hyphen, you can also exclude matching whitespace chars `\s`

```
(?<=-)[^-\s]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j6hrZL/1)